# Catching multiple keystrokes simultaneously in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have used 4 `NSButton`s and assigned them to the 4 arrow keys separately to move in four different directions. Now I want to use two keystrokes, left arrow and up arrow together simultaneously, for north east movement, how can I do it?

I am only able to use one keystroke at a time , I need to catch two key strokes simultaneously, I need it for my game project.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what programming language you use

Comment: @das_weezul: When somebody talks about Cocoa and NSButton, assume he uses Objective-C unless he says anything else ;-)

Comment: @Mecki: Thanks! I'm completely blank when it comes to objective-c and apple ;o)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Williham: Why would you use NSButtons to capture key events? This is pretty unusual. You capture key events by actually "capturing" them. E.g. by subclassing NSView.

Please excuse that the code below is very compact, but I don't want to waste more space than necessary:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

enum {
    upKeyPressed    = 1,
    leftKeyPressed  = 2,
    downKeyPressed  = 4,
    rightKeyPressed = 8
};

@interface MyView : NSView
{
    uint32_t pressedKeys_;
}
@end

@implementation MyView

- (void)makeMyWindowKey:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // Force app to foreground
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    // Make window key and display on screen
    [[timer userInfo] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    // YES, we want to be first responder
    return YES;
}

- (void)printPressedKeys
{
    printf("Keys currently pressed: ");
    if (!pressedKeys_) {
        printf("NONE");
    } else {
        if (pressedKeys_ & upKeyPressed) {
            printf("UP ");
        }
        if (pressedKeys_ & downKeyPressed) {
            printf("DOWN ");
        }
        if (pressedKeys_ & leftKeyPressed) {
            printf("LEFT ");
        }
        if (pressedKeys_ & rightKeyPressed) {
            printf("RIGHT ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)anEvent;
{
    BOOL printPressedKeys = YES;    
    switch ([anEvent keyCode]) {
        case 126: // UP
        pressedKeys_ &= ~upKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        case 123: // LEFT
        pressedKeys_ &= ~leftKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        case 125: // DOWN
        pressedKeys_ &= ~downKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        case 124: // RIGHT
        pressedKeys_ &= ~rightKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        default:
        // Ignore this key
        printPressedKeys = NO;
    }
    if (printPressedKeys) {
        [self printPressedKeys];
    }
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)anEvent;
{
    BOOL printPressedKeys = YES;
    switch ([anEvent keyCode]) {
        case 126: // UP
        pressedKeys_ |= upKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        case 123: // LEFT
        pressedKeys_ |= leftKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        case 125: // DOWN
        pressedKeys_ |= downKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        case 124: // RIGHT
        pressedKeys_ |= rightKeyPressed;
        break;
        
        case 53: // ESC
        // QUIT
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:self];
        // Fallthrough
        
        default:
        printPressedKeys = NO;
    }
    
    if (printPressedKeys) {
        [self printPressedKeys];
    }
}
@end

int main (
    int argc,
    char ** argv
) {
    // We need a pool, since we won't call NSApplicationMain
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    // W/o calling NSApplicationMain, we must do this before drawing UI
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    
    NSWindow * win = [[NSWindow alloc]
        initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500)
        styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
        defer:YES
    ];
    MyView * mv = [[MyView alloc] init];
    [win setContentView:mv];
    // Retained by window anyway
    [mv release];
    
    // Since we are no real UI application by now and since we have
    // no Info.plist, we must programmatically become a UI process,
    // which is in fact possible
    ProcessSerialNumber myProcess = { 0, kCurrentProcess };
    TransformProcessType(
        &myProcess,
        kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication
    );

    // The window we just created is our main window
    [win becomeMainWindow];
    
    // Our view is the first responder
    [win setInitialFirstResponder:[win contentView]];
    
    // We want the window to become key as soon as main runloop is running
    [NSTimer
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
        target:mv
        selector:@selector(makeMyWindowKey:)
        userInfo:win
        repeats:NO
    ];
    
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] run];

    // We should never get here
    
    // Remove window from screen and discard
    [win orderOut:nil];
    [win release];
    
    [pool release];
    printf("Quitting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Store in test.m, compile using

```
gcc -framework Cocoa -o test test.m
```

run using

```
./test
```

Monitor the output in Terminal while pressing arrow keys, quit by pressing ESC key. As you can see, it will print UP LEFT if both, up arrow and left arrow key are pressed and it will say DOWN RIGHT if down and right arrow key are pressed.

## Update

**user2051552** posted the following comment:

> Mecki your answer works perfectly for two keys. What if I wanted three
> or even four arrow keys pressed down at the same time? Thanks.

My code would also work for three or four keys being pressed at once, it's just limited by the way how keyboards work. Keyboards arrange keys as a grid of rows and columns. Every key pressed activates one row and one column. If you are holding down one key and then press a second one, either a different row and column is activated, or just another row or just another column if both keys sit on the same row or column. Either way, the keyboard is still able to figure out exactly which two keys are currently pressed.

Things get more complicated once you are holding down two keys at the same time and then press a third one. If the third one sits on the same row or column as one of the keys you were already holding down, the keyboard is not able to figure out anymore which key exactly you have pressed. That's because there are five possible combinations of three pressed keys that all five activate exactly the same two rows and columns, so your keyboard cannot say for sure which of those five combinations you are currently holding down. As a result the keyboard will not inform the system about a third keypress; it knows that you just pressed a third key, but it cannot tell for sure which key you just pressed, so it ignores this event. Only once you release one of the three keys, the mapping will become non-ambiguous again and the keyboard can update the pressed key information in the keyboard driver.

Note that I did not say you cannot press three keys at once. You can press three, four or even more keys at once, this will work just fine, as long as adding another key does not cause any ambiguity. But whenever it is ambiguous which keys you have pressed, the keyboard prefers to not report any keys at all to the system rather than possible reporting wrong keys. Just think about all the bad effects reporting wrong keys may cause (data may got corrupted, files may got deleted, etc., and there isn't always an UNDO function that will save you).

The effect of keypresses being ignored by the keyboard because they are ambiguous is named **Keyboard Ghosting**. **[See this Microsoft page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170909172645/http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/AntiGhostingExplained.mspx)** for a lengthy explanation on Keyboard Ghosting, with lots of images that can probably explain the problem much better than me. Especially the last image of that page is interesting, it shows you how five different keypress situations all five activate the same two rows and same two columns and thus cannot be distinguished anymore.

How many simultaneously pressed "arrow keys" your keyboard can distinguish of course depends on the fact how your keyboard vendor has "wired" those keys. In theory you can make sure all four arrow keys are distinguishable, but why would you want to do that? When you press more than two arrow keys at once, you either have to press "up and down" or "left and right" simultaneously and such a key combination is pointless. What do you expect your system to do when you tell it "go left and right"? Where should it go in that case? It makes sense to detect two arrow keys, so you can tell the system to "go up and left" or to "go down and right", since this would be a "diagonal motion", but there is no meaningful combination of three arrow keys.

That's why all keyboards on the market are wired in such a way, that **any meaningful combination of two arrow keys** is for sure detected correctly; this is necessary for "diagonal directions" to work as expected. However, beyond that, any other key combination may or may not work. E.g. on my keyboard certain combinations of three arrow keys do actually work (regardless the fact, that they are not meaningful), other ones do not. This is vendor specific and the effects on your keyboard may vary. There exist a few (usually rather expensive) keyboards on the market, that are (or at least claim to be) fully *Non-Ghosting*, either for all keys or at least for a subset of the keys. Those are often merchandised as "Gamer Keyboards", since gamers that play complex games and have to press many keys at once are of course heavily affected by ghosting in certain situations (and nothing is more annoying than dying in a game, just because your keyboard did not detect a keypress that would have saved your life).

So user2051552, if you can never see more than two arrow key presses at once, this is a hardware limitation of your keyboard, not of my code. Maybe if you buy a better keyboard, all four arrow keys at once can be detected. Also my code is only monitoring the arrow keys, if you modify it to monitor other keys as well, I'm pretty sure you can press the keys like "left", "up", "R", "A", and "X" at the same time and all keypresses will be noticed correctly.

Comment: Mecki your answer works perfectly for two keys. What if I wanted three or even four arrow keys pressed down at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: @user2051552 My answer would work for any number of key presses. You are just running into a hardware limitation of your keyboard, called **Keyboard Ghosting**. I updated my answer to explain the problem to you, there is also a very helpful link to a page with several images that explains the problem very well.

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn ObjC++ and this was soooo helpful thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a different approach for that, such as an NSView that intercepts the keys directly; rather than using separate NSButtons. Just a thought. (The event for this is `keyDown`, btw.)

**Edit:** You might also want to look into learning to crawl before you can walk; before you delve straight into the game programming, you should probably familiarize yourself with the responder chain, `NSEvent` and friends, and `NSResponder`, specifically `NSView`.

To be even more specific, you need to subclass `NSView` (the subclass you are using to show your game tableau should do nicely) and override

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

These will let you track key presses in a far more sophisticated manner.

You will find all the documentation you need for this in the Xcode Help menu.